# Weka vs Mahout for recommendation engine

Tags: java, weka, mahout, recommendation-engine

I am looking to come up with a collaborative filtering solution. I am quite comfortable with Java and found that a recommendation engine can be built using both Weka or Mahout. I have not built one before, so which one would be better to start out with?

Answer (score 1):

Both should work just fine.

The decision on which to use probably depends mostly on what other infrastructure/tools you plan to use: for example if you are using Hadoop then Mahout is probably a better fit. If you are doing in-memory analysis then Weka is probably a bit more comprehensive and mature.

Comment: Mahout has both Hadoop-based and pure Java (in-memory) recommenders -- in fact it's more the latter.

Comment: @SeanOwen I will not work on Hadoop or with big data. Still should I consider about Mahout? What are the pros and cos using Mahout instead of Weka at my position? Does Mahout has good documentation as like Weka? If you can answer my questions I will be able to select one of them for my project.

Comment: Weka has more docs and a longer history. For recommenders, I think Mahout has more to offer; for other approaches (and not Hadoop based) I think Weka is a good bet.